# "answered in" or "answered"?

Tags: phrases, meaning-in-context, prepositions, prepositional-phrases

I'm confused whether the verb *answer* should come with the preposition *in* or without it in a sentence "the timing a question will be *answered* *in* is important" or "the timing a question will be *answered* is important"? If both sentences are right, is there any difference in the meaning between the two?

Also, does the sentence sound natural or it should be rephrased?

Comment: 'The time a question will be answered in' refers to how long it takes to give an answer. 'The time a question will be answered' refers to the time of day, or which month etc, it will be answered.

Comment: Neither.  If I understand the context it should be something like "the time taken to answer the question is important" if you want to know how long it takes, or "the time at which the question is answered is important" if you wish to know the time-of-day.

Answer (score 1):

Alternatives:

*"The **timing** **of** answer**ing** a question is important"*

*"The **time** **of** answer**ing** a question is important"*

Different.

> timing =  selection **for maximum effect of the precise moment** for
>   beginning or doing something
>
> Merriam-Webster Unabridged Dictionary